# JavaFX - ToggleButton basics

Tags: java, button, javafx, togglebutton

I have two `ToggleButton` objects that are inside the same `GridPane`.

```
ToggleButton a = new ToggleButton("A");
ToggleButton b = new ToggleButton("B");
grid.addRow(1, a, b,);
```

If I press `a`, `b` un-presses. I cannot press `a` to un-press `a`. I would like each button to act independently of the other. Meaning pressing `a` does nothing to `b`, and if `a` was previously pressed, it would then un-press.

I tried doing

```
a.setToggleGroup(null)
```

but this does not change anything.

How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your full code. Buttons works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. I looked very closely and I do see a minor color change of the buttons if I stare hard. I'm going to change the colors to make it look more apparent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the functionality is working. It's just that the JavaFX focus color is obscuring the `pressed` coloration of the button. I changed the colors in css to make the `pressed` more obvious to the user.